# Issue understanding Ruby error: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I'm fairly new to Ruby and have tried to research this problem. Here is the code so far. I don't seem to have this problem calling the user object (user.deal_one(mydeck.deal_card)), but when I call it on the dealer I get this same error. The dealer object has the same instance variables and am unsure why it is calling on the method '<<'.

Here is the full error: blackjackOOP.rb:32:in `deal_one': undefined method`<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from blackjackOOP.rb:106:in `'

```
class Deck
  def initialize
    @deck = []
    @suit = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
    @value = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]
    @count = 0

    @value.each do |x|
      @suit.each do |y|
        @deck[@count] = [x, y]
        @count += 1
      end
    end
    @deck.shuffle!
  end

  def deal_card
    @card = []
    @card << @deck.pop
    @card
  end

  def show_deck_size
    puts @deck.size
  end
end 

module Hand
  def deal_one(card)
    @hand << card
  end

  def total
    @total = 0
    @hand.each do |card|
      card.each do |val, suit|
        if val == "Jack" || val == "Queen" || val == "King"
          @total += 10
        elsif val != "Ace"
          @total += val
        elsif val == "Ace"
          if @total > 10
            @total += 1
          else
            @total += 11
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class Player
  include Hand

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @hand = []
  end

  def hit_stay
    puts "#{@name} has #{show_hand} for a total of #{@total}"
  end

  def show_hand
    @hand.each do |card|
      card.each do |val, suit|
        print "#{val} of #{suit} "
      end
    end
  end
end

class Dealer
  include Hand

  def initalize
    @name = "Dealer"
    @hand = []
  end
end

def say(n)
  puts "=> #{n}"
end



say("Hello would you like to play some blackjack? Great!")
say("What is your name?")
name = gets.chomp

mydeck = Deck.new
user = Player.new(name)
dealer = Dealer.new

say("Welcome #{name}! Let's play!")


#deal hands to dealer and player
user.deal_one(mydeck.deal_card)
user.deal_one(mydeck.deal_card)
dealer.deal_one(mydeck.deal_card)
```

Comment: [Please accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369303/issue-understanding-ruby-error-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-nomethod/21369424#21369424) if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in your Dealer class.

You wrote `def initalize` and it should be `def initialize`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit The way to find stuff like this is to put it in a pry session and look how the objects look. When calling the Player.new method the resulting object looks very different to a dealer object that results from a Dealer.new session. What stands out is that dealer.hand is not initialized. This leaves only few places the actual error can be.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Its well worth it for quick testing of small ruby code. irb is another alternative for quick testing although pry has many powerful features that irb lacks.